# Equivalent definition of geometric vector bundles over schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, schemes

The following is Hartshonre's definition of geometric vector bundles:

> Let $Y$ be a scheme. A (geometric) vector bundle of rank $n$ over $Y$ is a scheme $X$ and a morphism $f:X\to Y$ together with additional data consisting of an open covering $\{U_i\}$ of $Y$ and isomorphisms $\psi_i:f^{-1}(U_i)\to \mathbb A^{n}_{U_i}$ such that for any $i,j$, and for any open affine subset $V=\operatorname{Spec}A \subseteq U_i\cap U_j$ the automorphism $\psi = \psi_j\circ\psi_{i}^{-1}$ of $\mathbb A^{n}_{V}$ is given by a linear automorphism $\theta$ of $A[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$, i.e, $\theta(a)=a$ for any $a\in A$ and $\theta(x_i)=\sum a_{ij}x_j$ for suitable $a_{ij}\in A$.

It is easy to show that a vector bundle of rank $n$ is equivalent to the data $\{U_i,\psi_{ij}\}$, where $\{U_i\}$ is an open covering of $Y$, $\psi_{ij}:\mathbb{A}_{U_i\cap U_j}^n \to\mathbb{A}_{U_j\cap U_i}^n$ are isomorphisms satisfying cocycle condition (i.e. $\psi_{ik}=\psi_{jk}\circ \psi_{ij}$), which are induced by linear automorphisms when restricted to open affine subsets $V\subseteq U_i\cap U_j$.

**My question is** :

Is a vector bundle of rank $n$ equivalent to the data $\{U_i,\Psi_{ij}\}$, where $\{U_i\}$ is an open covering of $Y$, and $\Psi_{ij}\in GL_n(\mathcal{O}(U_i\cap U_j))$ satisfying cocycle condition?

I know that $\Psi_{ij}\in GL_n(\mathcal{O}(U_i\cap U_j))$ give us morphisms $T_{ij}: U_i\cap U_j \to GL_n$ which satisfy cocycle condition.  And in the manifold case, a vector bundle is equivalent to the data $\{U_i,T_{ij}\}$. So I wonder if it still holds in algebraic geometry.

Comment: I believe it still holds. For the most part, rank $n$ vector bundles are classified by $H^1(X,GL_n(O_X))$.

Comment: @AHappyMathematician Where can I find this proposition? Thank you.

Comment: The data you described in your question defines a Cech cocycle in $C^1(X, GL_n(O_X))$, which would define an element in the first sheaf cohomology(cf. Hartshorne exercise III.4.4). I still think you need to check the equivalence in your question.

Comment: @Eric I can't recall a good reference, but as Daniel said, you still need to check the equivalence of the claim. My point was that they are equivalent because this fact is known to be true. I think the main difficulty here is seeing that $\psi_{ij}$ being a linear automorphism when restricted to an open affine subset implies these are elements $\Psi_{ij}\in GL_n(O(U_i\cap U_j))$...